# Firebase and Facebook API Calls

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, firebase, facebook-javascript-sdk, firebase-authentication

I am in need of some help. I am building an application and have run into a bump.  I'm trying to make API calls to the Graph API from Facebook but not under a new account.  I am using linkwithredirect to link a Facebook account to an email and password account on firebase.  After this is complete everytime i try and make a call to the graph API it says my account is already linked.  `

```js
facebook.addEventListener('click', e => {  
// First, we perform the signInWithRedirect.
// Creates the provider object.
var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
    
    provider.addScope('public_profile');
    provider.addScope('email');
    provider.addScope('user_photos');
    provider.addScope('manage_pages');
    provider.addScope('publish_pages');
    provider.addScope('business_management');
    provider.addScope('read_insights');
   // provider.addScope('public_actions');
// You can add additional scopes to the provider:x
    auth.currentUser.linkWithRedirect(provider).then(function(){
    firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {
          if (result.credential) {
            // This gives you a Google Access Token.
            // You can use it to access the Google API.
            facebookToken = result.credential.accessToken;
            // The signed-in user info.
            var user = result.user;
          }
        }).catch(function(error) {
          // Handle Errors here.
          var errorCode = error.code;
          var errorMessage = error.message;
        
          console.log(errorMessage + " Code:" + errorCode);
        });
    });
        if(user){
        FB.api('/me', {fields: 'last_name'}, function(response) {
            document.getElementById('status').innerHTML= response.last_name;
            console.log(response);
        });
        document.getElementById('facebook').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById('fbunlink').style.visibility = 'visible';
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML= 'You are not logged in.';
        document.getElementById('facebook').style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById('fbunlink').style.visibility = 'hidden';
       }
});
```

Comment: Once a provider is linked, you can't link it again. It is a one time operation. You are also checking redirect result in the linkWithRedirect promise. You need to move that externally.

Comment: so you are suggesting I just use a signinwithredirect?  I'm trying to link multiple social media accounts to a single email based account and have a user be able to access the API's of twitter, google and facebook.  I'm just starting with Facebook but keep running into that provider already linked error :(

Comment: There are multiple issues in your code. Once you link a provider, you can't link it again. You will get that error. If you want to test with that same account, delete and try again or use the unlink('facebook.com') API. Second, if you developing for a web app, linkWithRedirect will redirect the page and getRedirectResult will never run. You need to call that outside and not in the linkWithRedirect call.